# How to zoom in cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

I am attempting to edit the boundaries of a map using the `EuroPP()` projection in cartopy. I have written the following code, but hope to zoom in on the Scandinavia region. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.EuroPP())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', linewidth = 0.5)
ax.gridlines()

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)

tile = cimgt.StamenTerrain()
ax.add_image(tile,5)

plt.show()
```

The code produces the following image:
[image: What the code produces]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [set_extent](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.set_extent) to "zoom" into the desired region, in your case, just create a bounding box around Scandinavia. Add the following code right before `plt.show()`:

```
ax.set_extent([0, 43, 54, 75])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! What do those numbers mean exactly?

Comment: They are the latitudes and longitudes of the bounding box.

lower left corner: latitude = 54, longitude = 0

upper right corner: latitude = 75, longitude = 43